# Include all of a template library in a file

Tags: c++, boost, header

Off late I have had too use some template libraries like Boost and Thrust (for CUDA) in some of my coding work.

For using a certain feature of the Boost library, one has to include the appropriate header.e.g. for `boost::lexical_cast` I have to use `boost/lexical_cast.hpp`. It is tiring to keep including the appropriate header  for every new feature of Boost / Thrust which I use for my projects.

Is there any "shortcut" to tell the pre-processor  to include all the header files stored under the  boost library, so that I need not bother about which header file to include?

I am using GCC under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply make a mother-of-all header file like so:

```
for i in $(find /usr/include/boost/); do echo "#include <"${i/"/usr/include/"/}">"; done > master_header.hpp
```

Now you can add that and use precompiled headers (you may need an overnight compilation to make the PCH). You should also pass `-Wl,-as-needed` to the linker to avoid including unneeded libraries.

As @sbi says, this isn't advisable in the least, but since you asked... sometimes the best remedy against finding something "tiresome" is to see how much worse it could be!

Comment: Well, here have a `+1` for technically answering the question. I was a bit harsher than saying "not advisable", though.

Comment: @sbi: if nothing else this will be a useful exercise at using available tools, and maybe play with PCHs... of course you're right that this is not going to be a realistic solution for any actual problem.

Comment: I'm with sbi on this one. I haven't tried, but I suspect this might make a grownup build workstation yelp like a puppy at the load, if you could even get it to compile.

Comment: @ Kerrek SB. I see your point. On a side note, what if I have some hand written headers stored in a folder `foo`, which is in my $PATH, and I want to include all the headers in it? Your suggested solution will certainly work, but just for kicks, is there any standard C / C++ way of doing this from the source code itself?

Comment: @curiousexplorer: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 6):

You don't want that. You want to include as little as possible. Compile times are abysmal in C++ as it is. Start to include everything everywhere and it is going to get worse even.

I have been working in a project where compilation on a decent single core CPU of the time took 50mins, linking 5-10mins. This hurts big time, if you're doing template stuff deep down in the foundations.

Boost comes with a bunch of stuff (like the MPL) that stretches the compiler to its utmost limits. It would be insane to include this stuff everywhere (except for a five-cpp-files kind of project).